# Picking an image from a set of images that is most likely to be compelling to a typical viewer

Tags: image-processing

Given a set of images on a webpage, what's a good way to pick a compelling image that is also representative of the webpage? The use case is displaying an image along with a description of a URL to a page, after a user includes it in a status update.

I've found some techniques to find the most interesting part of a single image. Example: http://berk.es/smartcropper/

So maybe I can use this notion of entropy to compare images in a set?

I am programming in ruby, so a pure ruby solution is preferable, but am open to others.

Comment: How do you define whether one image is more or less interesting than another one?

Comment: Microsoft AutoCollage has a "interesting image picker" built-in. Unfortunately I don't know how it works.

Comment: @MainMa the purpose of the selection is described in my question. i'm using the human english definition of "interesting", which is subjective. i suppose an implied part of my question is "which selection criteria have been proposed and implemented for guessing which image of a set will be most interesting to a large portion of typical humans"

Comment: What have you studied and your level of familiarity of composition in art? I'd suggest reading [a bit from Drawing Scenery](http://books.google.com/books?id=h0-8aHIHDKoC&lpg=PA7&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q&f=false) and consider at a *very* basic level of "what makes something interesting" before trying to determine a computer program to do this.  Glance also at [Why do yellow and red look good together in this photo?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29534/why-do-yellow-and-red-look-good-together-in-this-photo) from Graphic Design and reconsider the question you are asking.

Comment: haha, okay i appreciate the philosophical discussion, but let me clarify my goals. i am trying to pick an image from a set that is most likely to look nice as the featured image in an embed. sites like facebook do this. for example, i could say: pick the larges image in the <article> section of a webpage. this would work pretty well a lot of the time. my question is if there are any software packages out there that already do this and maybe other tricks already.

Comment: Your use case is far from "picking the most interesting image". That title question has a lot of ongoing research in image processing, computer vision, machine learning and psychovisual studies. Your **true** use case is "picking an image from a webpage that is most representative of that page content".

Comment: okay, i've updated my title and question!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a quick hash of ideas. I don't have any implementations to share.

**Best advice: use side-channel information:**

- Relative position (layout) of the image on the page.
- Look at the scripts attached to that image. Is that clickable (onclick)?
- Does it have a title?
- Does it have a title that shares important words with the title of the page?

**Not-so-best advice: use image information.**

*Not-so-best because these are known difficult open-ended problems, so a non-scientist will find it painful to implement or even use.*

- Images with beautiful histogram (e.g. suns, beaches, blue sky)
- ... any of the research publications mentioned by others in the comments.

**COTS (on-the-shelf) solutions:**

- Images with a face (mugshot). Search for "OpenCV face recognition Ruby" and you'll find some.

  - Instructions: http://www.sitepoint.com/detecting-faces-with-ruby-ffi-in-a-nutshell/ (No comments on this since I'm not a Ruby programmer)

**Advice for the true hackers.**

https://harthur.github.io/brain/

This is a submission (as seen on Hacker News) that trains a simple neural network (3 input nodes, 3 nodes in a middle layer) based on whether the user prefers black text or white text against a RGB background.

A similar do-it-yourself approach can be applied to an image histogram picker. However, we wouldn't know how useful the end result would be for your applications.